# Reduce numbers with a minimal cost without minheaps

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have n numbers and an operation to add two numbers to produce a new number. The **cost** of such an operation is **equal to sum of numbers**.

The **final cost** is the **sum of all intermediate** costs.
The question is what is a **minimal final cost** to reduce numbers to one number.

example:

```
[5, 3, 3, 4, 20] -> minimum cost = 6 + 9 + 15 + 35 = 65 
3 + 3 = 6    // after the operation I have an array: [5, 6, 4, 20]
4 + 5 = 9    // [9, 6, 20]
6 + 9 = 15   // [15, 20]
15 + 20 = 35 // [35]
```

I am wondering if there is any simple solution for this faster than O(n**2) without introducing non-standard JS data structures (i.e. min-max heaps).

I know that additional structures can be implemented but such a solution is not 'simple' as requires a lot of extra code (but maybe they can be reduced to solve only this particular problem?).

Comment: why do you get 65?

Comment: @nina that's the sum of all operations (6 + 9 + 15 + 35)

Comment: Can the operations be applied on any operands or do they have to be neighbours in the array? Otherwise I would've a O(n log n) solution

Comment: any operands, With min-heap it would be nlogn

Comment: with a min-heap, each iteration I would pop two smallest numbers, join them and insert back. Insertion is O(long) and pop() is O(1) so for every element, it would be O(nlogn)

Comment: @NinaScholz when two numbers are added they produce a cost and the resulting number goes back to the game. When only one number is left the game is over and the result is a sum of all costs.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the elements descending, then pop two elements, insert their sum, and add up the sums:

```
 input.sort((a, b) => b - a); // O(n log n)

 let cost = 0;

 while(input.length > 1) { // O(n²) :(
   const op = input.pop() + input.pop();
   cost += op;

   input.splice( // O(n) ? 
     binarySearch(input, op), // O(log n)
     0, 
     op
    );
 }

 function binarySearch(arr, value, min = 0, max = arr.length - 1) {
   const middle = Math.floor((min + max) / 2);
   if(value === arr[middle] || min === max)
     return middle;
   if(value < arr[middle])
     return binarySearch(arr, value, min, middle - 1);
   return binarySearch(arr, value, middle + 1, max);
 }
```

Comment: can you please explain your approach?

Comment: I will when I fixed it. It does not work at the moment. Problem: Given 6 as length, how do I get 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2 during iteration?

Comment: @grzim I think I've overcomplicated things, added a version that is hopefully easy to understand.

Comment: yes it is easy now, but sadly will not work properly;) You are pushing the sum of two smallest elements which can be bigger than the last element in an array. This means  - an array is no longer sorted. This is why min-heap would suit perfectly

Comment: I see ... finally understood the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could take one index for the unseen values and another to splice the array for adding a sum at the right place.

At the end add all values.

```js
var data = [5, 3, 3, 4, 20],
    result,
    i = 0;

data.sort((a, b) => a - b);

while (data.length - i > 2) {
    let sum = data[i++] + data[i++],
        j = i;
    while (data[j] < sum) j++;
    data.splice(j, 0, sum);
}

result = data.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
   
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is O(n²) (like my version) (assuming splice is O(n))